# Remove notification when service destroyed by android OS

Tags: android, service, android-ondestroy

I created an app which shows Notification when `Service.onStartCommand()` method executed and hide notification when `Service.onDestroy()` is called. Its works fine for normal calls to startService() and stopService().

**Service Code:**

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
    nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    //Some  code here
    showNotification();
    return START_NOT_STICKY; 
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    nm.cancel(R.string.service_started);
}
```

**Problem:** When my service is destroyed by android OS() (In case when `onDestroy()` not called) then notification not removed. So how to remove notification when Service is destroyed by android OS itself?

Answer (score 1):

Always call your code BEFORE `super.onDestroy();` and not AFTER

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    nm.cancel(R.string.service_started);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: this also does not always work. onDestroy might be skipped by android

Answer (score 0):

You should use this where ever u want to stop the service,that will close your notification and end service.

```
stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `notificationManager.cancelAll()`

If you're targeting API 24+ `stopForeground(Service.STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE)` or `stopForeground(true)`

Also you should probably look into [onTrimMemory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTrimMemory(int)) and [onLowMemory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onLowMemory()) which are function called when the OS destroy your service.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
stopForeground(true)
```

When your work will complete.It will destroy foreground notification.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely you are not stopping your service

Comment: I m stopping service and this is works fine in that case. But when my service is destroyed by android OS()(may be on low memory or something else) then how to remove notification

Comment: @user1041858 Why do you think onDestroy won't be called in this case?

Comment: I have this problem when android system automatically destroy service.

Comment: @user1041858 Documentation says onDestroy will be called in such case. I've never checked that out though.

Comment: But onDestroy() not called in this case immediately (May be called after some time) so notification not removed